# Regexp range selection

Tags: json, regex

I need to find a key value pair of a JSON document using regular expression. The problem is that I can't properly understand how to scope the selection of the matching data.

Using this regexp,

```
"email"\s*:\s*".*"
```

it will select the entire document till it finds the last `"`.

[image]

But i wanted to only select up-to the first `"` so the selection would be like this:

> "email":"foobar@foo.bar"

In order to achieve this I have tried using anchors like this:

```
"email"\s*:\s*^".*"$
```

but it is not working as expected.
What would be a better way to achieve this?

Please note that if the email contains a double quote then the json string will be like this:

```
{"email":"foo@bar.c\"om"}
```

In this above scenario we might need to be able to skip all the `\"` as well?

Also I need to fetch this data from a large file with 1.6m + inline JSON documents.

Playground: https://regexr.com/552pt

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse JSON, they are not suited for that. Instead, use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Using `json_decode()` makes it so slow actually

Answer (score 0):

Just add a question mark to cause it to look for the minimum instead of the maximum

```
"email"\s*:\s*".*?"
```

Comment: What if the email contains already a double quote ? It's a valid format

Comment: @Cid Good point actually, and yes it breaks if the email contains already a double quote.

Comment: We might need to skip `\"` from a string like this `{"email":"foo@bar.c\"om"}`?

Comment: The name part of an email address can technically be enclosed in double quotes, but it can't contain just one double quote, as far as I know. But that format is also disallowed by most webmail providers such as Gmail, and so could also be disallowed by whatever is producing that JSON.

Comment: If you really want to skip `\"`, this should do: `"email"\s*:\s*".*?((?<!\\)")`. I know this is what you want, but you should really be using a json parser. You're going to expand upon this regex with edge cases until it becomes incomprehensible.